# Protections for writers of recommend letters

Tags: recommendation-letter

I was reading online some of the legal troubles in the US that can occur to recommend letter writers.  I imagine that many of us are familiar with (at least some of the) FERPA regulations.  We must obtain (in writing) a signed permission to use grades, and (at least according to one place I found) we are also required to inform the letter receiver not to convey that information to a third party without written consent.

At many receiving institutions, during the submission process there is a (sometimes large) legal disclaimer.  At some institutions, this includes something to the effect of "Law prevents us from keeping your letter confidential.  We will protect your identity, unless a court says we cannot.  etc..."

Some employers keep a permanent file containing the recommend letters.  As we all know, details over time become fuzzy, and so this seems to leave a letter writer open to litigation if details in the letter are disputed (by *either* a disgruntled employer or the one we write the letter for).

What protections exist for those who write recommend letters?  In particular, can letter writers give a time limit to how long an employer may keep a letter?  Apparently, in countries outside the US, letters of recommend are very short, to avoid legal issues.

Comment: Honesty and truthfulness are your main protection.

Comment: My employer absolutely does not keep letters around for any length of time, not least because there is no driver to do so, and legal liability if doing so.

Comment: There are legal protections in the US. The bar is fairly high for charges of libel. See https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/libel

Comment: In the U.S., grades and anything else that is an "education record" are protected by FERPA, hence the caution not to convey such information to third parties.  That absolutely does not keep the *subject* of the letter from seeing it.

Comment: @JonCuster Absolutely! Once a hiring / admission decision is made, such letters are no longer useful.  A wise lawyer once told me, "They can't subpoena what you don't have."

Comment: I'm thinking more along the lines of copyright/use protections, and not libel (although I like Bob Brown's point).  If I have a book that I want to share, I choose what level of copyright/use I will allow to protect myself and the user.  Why don't we do something similar with letters of recommend?  Eg. "You may use this letter for only six months.  You may not share it with a third party.  If you share it with the applicant, you must inform me in writing.  etc..."

Comment: _I was reading online..._ — Would you mind sharing some links?

Answer (score 1):

On mathjobs.org letter writers can give an expiration date for their letters.

I have no idea what would happen if a disgruntled applicant took some sort of legal action to obtain a copy of those letters.

To the best of my understanding (I'm not a lawyer, etc.), in the U.S., in academic settings, there are no genuine protections for letter-writers. Rather, if/when everyone behaves civilly, there's simply no issue.

This is why I try to demur when asked to write letters in situations that make me uneasy, especially when I feel compelled to say "I'm sorry, I'm not confident that I can write you a *helpful* letter. Perhaps someone else can do better."

Comment: The last paragraph is a wise policy. Highly recommended.

Comment: "if/when everyone behaves civilly"  The problem is that I wouldn't have even thought to warn a letter receiver not to share the letter with a 3rd party.  I'm looking for some standard document that one could attach to a letter (possibly as a link) laying out the "civil" uses of the letter.  Just like we have different levels of copyright on our other works.